# Telegram BOT - setWebhook not working

Tags: php, ssl, webhooks, telegram-bot

I'm new to creating telegram bots and I really don't know where to start.
Only thing I know about is PHP.

Making it simple I have a VPS with Windows Server 2008 R2 installed on it and I've made a self-signed certificate using

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout server.key -x509 -days 365 -out server.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
```

Then I converted PEM to CER using

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in server.pem -outform DER -out server.cer
```

I'v had WAMP server installed and set it to work with server.cer & server.key as certificate and key then I'v tested the HTTPS(443) and it worked.

Then I installed a REST client on the chrome and sent URL of the bot.php and PEM file as multipart form data as the official documentation said.

Now I get this error:

```
{
    ok: false,
    error_code: 400,
    description: "Error: Bad webhook: Posix Error: Success: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known"
}
```

and ... I'm here now ! :| asking you for help
What is the problem and how should I solve this

Thanks in advance :)

NOTE: I don't have a domain I'm using my VPS's IP

Comment: hey there!  did you solve this problem?? mind to share with us?

Comment: nope :( no one and nothing helped.

Comment: too late, but just for who redirects to your question,but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38409622/6478645) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Telegram requires valid ssl certificate for your **domain**.

I will tell how I solved this.

You can use NGROK that can expose local ip to the internet with temporary domain and https enabled.

Link to install - https://ngrok.com/

After you install it, just run in your console:

```
ngrok http 127.0.0.1:8003
```

(ofc use `ip` and `port` of from your `WAMP` configuration)

and you will get a free temporary domain (it will look like `https://f9eb2f08.ngrok.io`) with https enabled.

Then set url with your new domain as a telegram webhook_url and bot's requests will go to your local server as long as NGROK is running.