# set webhook for telegram bot and what is self sign certificate

Tags: jsp, telegram-bot

I set webHook for my telegram bot by this :

```
> https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>/setWebhook?url=https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp
```

I don't set any certificate for this.
But when I (or a telegram user) send message to this bot, https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp does not get any request!! when I send any kind of message to robot, no request gotten by https://mywebapp.com/index.jsp. What should I do? Is certificate necessary for telegram bot webhook?

Comment: Do you have a valid certificate?

Comment: No I don't! Is it necessary to have valid certificate? How can I make it?@Johannes Kuhn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need a valid SSL certificate for webhooks to work.
- To use a self-signed certificate, you need to upload your public key certificate - using the certificate parameter in setWebhook. Please upload as InputFile, - sending a String will not work.
- Ports currently supported for Webhooks: 443, 80, 88, 8443.
- Wildcard certificates may not be supported.
- Redirects are not supported.
- CN must exactly match your domain.

Answer (score 0):

open https://requestb.in/ and "Create a RequestBin" as listener for callback URL

It is no need any certificate file because it has valid ssl.

Be sure it works, other wise some think is wrong.